# Array Mapping and maybe a dictionary--what is this code doing?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Still new to Angular and this is production code that I'm going to have to refactor, but I can't really understand what it's doing.

```
        const { productIdSet = [] } = this.selectedStayLevelConfig;
        this.selectedProductIds = productIdSet.map(({ productIdCode }) => productIdCode);
```

What I can tell you is that AuthorizationOptionValueDependantConfig looks like this.

```
interface AuthorizationOptionValueDependantConfig extends Serializable {
    allowBackdating?: boolean;
    attachmentRequired?: boolean;
    attachmentRequiredMessage?: string;
    backdatingLimit?: number;
    defaultProcedureCode?: string;
    defaultProcedureCodeSet?: string;
    defaultProcedureId?: string;
    defaultProcedureName?: string;
    extendLineItemAttachmentRequired?: boolean;
    extendLineItemAttachmentRequiredMessage?: string;
    extendLineItemNoteDefinitionId?: string;
    extendLineItemNoteRequired?: boolean;
    noteDefinitionId?: string;
    noteRequired?: boolean;
    optionGroup?: OptionGroup;
    optionValueId?: string;
    productIdSet?: AuthorizationOptionValueProductId[];
    useDefaultProcedure?: boolean;
}
```

As you can see, it has a member called productIdSet which is an AuthorizationOptionValueProductId. Here is that:

```
interface AuthorizationOptionValueProductId extends Serializable, Comparable<AuthorizationOptionValueProductId> {
    optionValueProductId?: number;
    productIdCode?: string;
}
```

So can someone tell me what the structure is that this code creates and what this code is actually doing?

Comment: The first line takes an array of `productIdSet` from `selectedStayLevelConfig` with object deconstruction. The second maps an array `productIdSet` to an array of `productIdCode` again with deconstruction. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: You know, I keep not finding stuff in Angular docs and forget to look in javascript. Thanks for the help! Do you want to post as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Another good resource: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#destructuring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ritaj pointed out:

The first line takes an array of productIdSet from selectedStayLevelConfig with object deconstruction. The second maps an array productIdSet to an array of productIdCode again with deconstruction.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

I always forget to look at javascript for answers to my Angular questions.